# Filtering unique data and summing their values on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following table with six columns,

```
1313109100  7   1313112110  1   1313112110  2
2313135510  18  1313109100  6   1313109100  7
1313114829  2   1313114829  2   1313114829  2
0313155000  2   2313135510  19  2313135510  15
1313114605  1   0313155000  2   0313155002  2
1311121116  1   1311121116  1   1311121114  1
0312302700  1   0312302700  1   2312302700  1
0313107100  2   1313114605  1   1313114605  1
2313130000  2   0313107100  4   2313147600  2
2313147600  2   2313147600  4   2313130000  2
1313112110  1   2313130000  4   0313107100  1
```

I want to filter out the unique values for the first columns and see their total amounts.

I can filter the unique values easily but some values are starting with 0 so I have to convert all of the column to text in order to see them correctly. On the other hand, the excel counts number and text twice.

How can I accomplish this?

I have solved my problem by converting all the 10 digit column to numbers than using an If statement to add 0 in front. After that I used sumifs command to find out the total numbers of unique 10 digits.

Thanks for your effort

Comment: What have you tried? And summing numbers beginning with 0 shouldn't matter, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am basically trying to eliminate duplicate 10 digit numbers but not the total amount of them. In the end, I want to end up with unique 10 digits and their total amounts.

Comment: So you want to count `001`, `1` and `01` three times, but sum them to `1`? They won't match as text, but they will match as values?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a sumproduct like this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A12,INT(A1:A12)),INT(A1:A12))
```

If you mean to sum column B

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A7,INT(A1:A7)),(B1:B7))
```